# How to wait multiple messages properly and become new state after that

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor, that should receive two messages and after that, become new initialised state. I wrote some code, but it seems very ugly:

```
def waitInitialisation(@Nullable one: Integer, @Nullable two: String): Receive = {
  case _one: Int =>
    if (two == null)
      context.become(waitInitialisation(_one, two))
    else {
      doSomething()
      context.become(initialised(_one, two))
    }
  case _two: String =>
    if (one == null)
      context.become(waitInitialisation(one, _two))
    else {
      doSomething()
      context.become(initialised(one, _two))
    }
}    

def initialised(one: Int, two: String): Receive = ???

override def receive: Receive = waitInitialisation(null, null)
```

So problems, what I see: null checking and duplicate code. How I can simplify my implementation and make it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Option` is the idiomatic way in Scala to handle nulls:

```
def waitInitialisation(one: Option[Int], two: Option[String]): Receive = {
  case _one: Int =>
    two match {
      case Some(s) =>
        doSomething()
        context.become(initialised(_one, s))
      case None =>
        context.become(waitInitialisation(Option(_one), None))
    }

  case _two: String =>
    one match {
      case Some(i) =>
        doSomething()
        context.become(initialised(i, _two))
      case None =>
        context.become(waitInitialisation(None, Option(_two)))
    }
}

def initialised(one: Int, two: String): Receive = ???

def receive = waitInitialisation(None, None)
```

As for "code duplication," I wouldn't get hung up on the number of `become` calls. Your actor can be in one of the four following states:

- `waitInitialisation(None, None)`
- `waitInitialisation(Some, None)`
- `waitInitialisation(None, Some)`
- `initialised`

You probably could implement the state changes with the [`FSM`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/fsm.html) trait, but that would be overkill for your case. The way you've structured your actor is simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

@chunjef already gave a great direction in using Options which is the way to go in Scala. I'm letting below two other options in which I use pattern matching to make the code a bit more beautiful.

Before you take a look at the two solutions please bear in mind that usually calling `.get` on an `Option` is not recommended and will possibly get you some compiler warnings. Anyways, we're always sure to make the right call in our examples because we're checking beforehand if the option `isDefined`.

Oh, and when working with values that might come `null` - like operating with Java APIs - **always** use Option's apply, not Some's apply.

---

The first one defines essentially the same method but structured a bit differently:

```scala
def waitInit(one: Option[Int], two: Option[String]): Receive = {
  case value: Int if two.isDefined =>
    context.become(initialised(value, two.get))
  case value: Int =>
    context.become(waitInit(Option(value), two))
  case value: String if one.isDefined =>
    context.become(initialised(one.get, value))
  case value: String =>
    context.become(waitInit(one, Option(value)))
}

override val receive = waitInit(None, None)
```

---

The second one splits this logic in two pieces so you can follow on it easier:

```scala
def waitOne(two: Option[String]): Receive = {
  case one: Int if two.isDefined =>
    context.become(initialised(one, two.get))
  case one: Int =>
    context.become(waitOne(two) orElse waitTwo(Option(one)))
}

def waitTwo(one: Option[Int]): Receive = {
  case two: String if one.isDefined =>
    context.become(initialised(one.get, two))
  case two: String =>
    context.become(waitOne(Option(two)) orElse waitTwo(one))
}

override val receive: Receive =
  waitOne(None) orElse waitTwo(None)
```

---

That's it, I didn't put some code here (like the definition of `initialised`) essentially because it's the same.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that with an additional message.
With that solution, adding or changing messages for the init will be easy :

```
case class InitState(
    one : Option[Int], 
    two : Option[String], 
    three : Option[Boolean]      
)
{

  def fire() : Unit = {
    context.become(waitInit(this))
    self ! this
  }
}

def waitInit(st : InitState = InitState(None, None, None)) : Receive = {
  case i : Int =>       
    st.copy(one = Some(i)).fire()
  case s : String => 
    st.copy( two = Some(s)).fire()
  case b : Boolean =>
    st.copy(three = Some(b)).fire()

  case InitState(Some(i : Int), Some(s : String), Some(b : Boolean)) =>
    context.become(afterInit(i, s, b))

  case _ : InitState =>  

}

def afterInit(one : Int, two : String, three : Boolean) : Receive = ???    
def receive = waitInit()
```

As chunjef wrote, for not so simple cases, the good choice will be using FSM.

Answer (score 0):

`akka-contrib` provided this Aggregator pattern that is similar to what you are looking for: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-contrib/src/main/scala/akka/contrib/pattern/Aggregator.scala

This code is now deprecated but you can copy it into your project.

Here you can find how it works (this documentation is pretty old): http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0/contrib/aggregator.html

The main idea is to use `expect` or `expectOnce` to receive certain messages. Once that has happened, you can do whatever else.